# Bootstrap Collapsed Navbar Button doesn´t Working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have two sites.
On the first, the Collapsed Navbar works: (Located at http://www.doca-rbz.de (Index Site))

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">DoCa</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Startseite</a></li>
        <li><a href="Kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
        <li><a href="Guestbook/index.php">G&auml;stebuch</a></li>
        <li><a href="ueber_uns.html">&Uuml;ber uns</a></li>
        <li><a href="Galerie.html">Galerie</a></li>
        <li><a href="lieferer.html">Partner</a></li>
        <li><a href="login.php">Intern</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

On the second page it doesn't work: (Located at http://www.doca-rbz.de/new_hp (also the index Site))

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><span> Sch&uuml;lercafe DoCa </span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="myNavbar" aria-expanded="false">
                <ul class="navbar-nav nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Startseite</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">G&auml;stebuch</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">&Uuml;ber uns</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Galerie</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Partenr</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <div class="container">
            <h1> Willkommen auf <span class="text-gold"> SERVERNAME </span></h1>



     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Why does the second one not work?

Some more information about for the code:

First code block:

- "Handmade"--I have written it myself
- Worked everytime

Second code block:

- Copied from other Site
- Under it is a Jumbotron (Bootstrap)
- <del>Has never worked</del>
  **Button opens now but doesn`t close it again**

Comment: You need to add bootstrap.js file on second website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are not properly adding "bootstrap.js" to the second website. I would recommend starting there - if not could you please update your question with the errors form your console or developer tools within your browser?

**Update**

```
<nav class = "navbar navbar-default" role = "navigation">

  <div class = "navbar-header">
     <button type = "button" class = "navbar-toggle" 
       data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#example-navbar-collapse">
       <span class = "sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
       <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
       <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
       <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
     </button>
      <a class = "navbar-brand" href = "#">TutorialsPoint</a>
    </div>

  <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id = "example-navbar-collapse">
    <ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
       <li class = "active"><a href = "#">iOS</a></li>
       <li><a href = "#">SVN</a></li>

       <li class = "dropdown">
          <a href = "#" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown">
             Java 
             <b class = "caret"></b>
          </a>

          <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
             <li><a href = "#">jmeter</a></li>
             <li><a href = "#">EJB</a></li>
             <li><a href = "#">Jasper Report</a></li>

             <li class = "divider"></li>
             <li><a href = "#">Separated link</a></li>

             <li class = "divider"></li>
             <li><a href = "#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>

       </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

This is how it should be set up - Please try this and let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Now i have added the boostrap.js on the second Website. Now the Button opens the Menu but it does not close it again...
When you need/want the whole code say it.

Comment: Could you please open your developer console and then repeat the steps - then could you please copy and paste the complete error. 

[Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)

[Safari](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=safari+developer+tools+enable)

[FireFox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Tools_Toolbox)

Comment: O.k. wait. 
In Error log was a Entry 404 for the bootstrap.min.js.
Now the Path is on my Webspace and there is only a 404 Error for a Picture
(http://www.team-scorpia.de/bootstrap/gommehd/images/jumbo/statistics.jpg 404 (Not Found)(anonymous function) @ jquery.js:3609j @ jquery.js:3148k.fireWith @ jquery.js:3260m.extend.ready @ jquery.js:3472J @ jquery.js:3503)

But what is now the error

Comment: Where in your HTML are you adding the bootstrap.min.js src script? It is recommended to have that moved to the bottom of your of your page by the right before the ending `</body>` tag

Comment: jquery.min.js
bootstrap.js
bootstrap.min.js

The Order of my Scripts and yes they are all at the bottom before the </body> tag

Comment: Looking back at your code for page two - seems like you have `navbar-toggle collapsed` then you are adding a `data-toggle="collapse"` Why are you calling it twice? did you create the `collapsed` class? Can you update your question with that bit of code?

Comment: @Error219, I have updated my original answer with a working version of how to properly implement this. Please reference the example.

Comment: Hmmm.
Sry doesn't work.
I think i have forgotton something. Which Scripts and in which order do you have?
I had a similiar Problem caused by the wrong order of the scripts and stylesheets

Comment: @Error219 :: Add these CDNs as the src path for your project.


**CSS**
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css

**JS**
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js

Comment: WORKS thank you. 
Thanks for fast answer everytime. 
Thanks for helping

Comment: np - glade its working, if you could please up vote my answer that would be wonderful! Cheers

Comment: i upvoted it but it is not visible because i have not 15 reputation only 6 ;) but if i have 15 i will do it so its visible